# Is it a good practice to write classes that typically have only one public method exposed?

Tags: unit-testing, design-patterns

The more I get into writing unit tests the more often I find myself writing smaller and smaller classes. The classes are so small now that many of them have only one public method on them that is tied to an interface. The tests then go directly against that public method and are fairly small (sometimes that public method will call out to internal private methods within the class). I then use an IOC container to manage the instantiation of these lightweight classes because there are so many of them.

Is this typical of trying to do things in a more of a TDD manner? I fear that I have now refactored a legacy 3,000 line class that had one method in it into something that is also difficult to maintain on the other side of the spectrum because there is now literally about 100 different class files.

Is what I am doing going too far? I am trying to follow the single responsibility principle with this approach but I may be treading into something that is an anemic class structure where I do not have very intelligent "business objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This multitude of small classes would drive me nuts. With this design style it becomes really hard to figure out where the real work gets done. I am not a fan of having a ton of interfaces each with a corresponding implementation class, either. Having lots of "IWidget" and "WidgetImpl" pairings is a code smell in my book.

Breaking up a 3,000 line class into smaller pieces is great and commendable. Remember the goal, though: it's to make the code easier to read and easier to work with. If you end up with 30 classes and interfaces you've likely just created a different type of monster. Now you have a really complicated class design. It takes a lot of mental effort to keep that many classes straight in your head. And with lots of small classes you lose the very useful ability to open up a couple of key files, pick out the most important methods, and get an idea of what the heck is going on.

For what it's worth, though, I'm not really sold on test-driven design. Writing tests early, that's sensible. But reorganizing and restructuring your class design so it can be more easily unit tested? No thanks. I'll make interfaces only if they make architectural sense, not because I need to be able to mock up some objects so I can test my classes. That's putting the cart before the horse.

Answer (score 1):

You might have gone a bit too far if you are asking this question. Having only one public method in a class isn't bad as such, if that class has a clear responsibility/function and encapsulates all logic concerning that function, even if most of it is in private methods.

When refactoring such legacy code, I usually try to identify the components in play at a high level that can be assigned distinct roles/responsibilities and separate them into their own classes. I think about which functions should be which components's responsibility and move the methods into that class.

Answer (score 0):

You write a class so that instances of the class maintain state. You put this state in a class because all the state in the class is related.You have function to managed this state so that invalid permutations of state can't be set (the infamous square that has members width and height, but if width doesn't equal height *it's not really a square*.)

If you don't have state, you don't need a class, you could just use free functions (or in Java, static functions).

So, the question isn't "should I have one function?" but rather "what state-ful entity does my class encapsulate?"

Maybe you have one function that sets all state -- and you should make it more granular, so that, e.g., instead of having `void Rectangle::setWidthAndHeight( int x, int y)` you should have a `setWidth` and a separate `setHeight`.

Perhaps you have a ctor that sets things up, and a single function that `doesIt`, whatever "it" is. Then you have a *functor*, and a single `doIt` might make sense. E.g., `class Add implements Operation { Add( int howmuch); Operand doIt(Operand rhs);}`

(But then you may find that you really want something like the Visitor Pattern -- a pure functor is more likely if you have purely value objects, Visitor if they're arranged in a tree and are related to each other.)

Even if having these many small objects, single-function is the correct level of granularity, you may want something like a facade Pattern, to compose out of primitive operations, often-used complex operations.

There's no one answer. If you really have a bunch of functors, it's cool. If you're really just making each free function a class, it's foolish.

The real answer lies in answering the question, "what state am I managing, and how well do my classes model my problem domain?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd be speculating if I gave a definite answer without looking at the code.

However it sounds like you're concerned and that is a definite flag for reviewing the code. The short answer to your question comes back to the [definition of Simple Design](http://martinfowler.com/articles/designDead.html#id21655). Minimal number of classes and methods is one of them. If you feel like you can take away some elements without losing the other desirable attributes, go ahead and collapse/inline them.

Some pointers to help you decide:

- Do you have a good check for "Single Responsibility" ? It's deceptively difficult to get it right but is a key skill (I still don't see it like the masters). It doesn't necessarily translate to one method-classes. A good yardstick is 5-7 public methods per class. Each class could have 0-5 collaborators. Also to validate against SRP, ask the question what can drive a change into this class ? If there are multiple unrelated answers (e.g. change in the packet structure (parsing) + change in the packet contents to action map (command dispatcher) ) , maybe the class needs to be split. On the other end, if you feel that a change in the packet structure, can affect 4 different classes - you've run off the other cliff; maybe you need to combine them into a cohesive class.
- If you have trouble naming the concrete implementations, maybe you don't need the interface. e.g. XXXImpl classes implmenting XXX need to be looked at. I recently learned of a naming convention, where the interface describes a Role and the implementation is named by the technology used to implement the role (or falling back to what it does). e.g. XmppAuction implements Auction (or SniperNotifier implements AuctionEventListener)
- Lastly are you finding it difficult to add / modify / test existing code (e.g. test setup is long or painful ) ? Those can be signs that you need to go refactoring.